# Searching in chosen-plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

When I search in chosen-plugin - it ignore content between symbols ". How can I change it? Could you write function, where I must change something.

I found function and changed it. Here my code.

```
Chosen.prototype.keydown_arrow = function() { //changed here
        var a;
        a = this.result_highlight.nextAll("li.active-result").first();
        a = a.replace(/[^"]/g, "");
        return this.results_showing && this.result_highlight ? (a) ? this.result_do_highlight(a) : void 0 : this.results_show()
    }
```

Where I made a mistake?
Maybe I must change another function?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize with parameter at first like below;

```
.chosen({ search_contains: true });
```

Comment: Could you help me, please? I've a problem with chosen again))

Comment: Sure Sergey, ask please)

Comment: I asked new question. Myabe you will hepl me. Please, follow the link. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266832/chosen-plugin-cut-down-string