# Chosen-plugin cut down string

Tags: jquery-chosen

My chosen-plugin doesn't work good. When I click on button, strings drop-down. But I feel plugin cut down part of string. How can I change it. Maybe is settings?

Comment: do you want the dropdown to show more options? How many are currently showing?

Comment: No, with drop-down all is ok. I meant each option in my drop-down is cutdown.

Comment: @sergey can you send an image what you described in the question ?

Comment: @KnowGe sure. I know my English is not so good (maybe, my description is bad)...I'm so sorry, I'm learning now))
http://prnt.sc/cz7qss - link on picture. 
there are ukrainian words. Some those words or part of string are cutted...Some strings are on two lines, some strings are cutted.

Comment: Priviet @sergey , I love your country, I came couples times) I didn't see anything wrong, width of strings is longer than width of dropdown. If you really want, every sentence should be just in one line you can increase width of dropdown or you can decrease font size of options with css

Comment: @KnowGe. Sorry, I was busy. In this screenshot some string are on two lines and some strings were cut. Why? Do you know why? Do you understand my English?

Comment: @KnowGe. I'd like to see all strings on two lines or, maybe, more than two. Can't I?

Comment: @sergey, I understood exactly 100% what you meant, but I think you didn't understand what I meant. http://jsfiddle.net/yo8hunqk/ I set text size to 34px for your attention. You can use same css, for example with 15px. or maybe less than 15 px for two lines options